# Antergos linux keeps freezing

Tags: openbox, freeze, antergos

By freeze I mean that only full reboot makes the system workable again. During the freeze the cursor is motionless, no keys are working (neither <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1-6</kbd> neither capslock/numlock) and the music starts looping (playing the last two seconds). I have four-core Intel celeron cpu, 120gb sda and 4gb of ram (during freezes no more than 1,5 Gb is used). The system is fully updated, the problem wasn't here when I was running Debian. Freeze usually happens once per hour, usually when midori browser (the problem was here when I was running firefox too) or dwarf fortress are open. I don't have desktop environment, I only have window manager Openbox. The freezing isn't recent phenomena, the system keeps freezing ever since I installed antergos.

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux Kepler 4.5.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 11 22:21:28 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Logs:

```
    -- Logs begin at čet 2016-04-21 15:50:11 CEST, end at pon 2016-05-23 15:50:33 CE
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler systemd-journald[163]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler systemd-journald[163]: System journal (/var/log/journal/)
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler systemd-journald[163]: Time spent on flushing to /var is
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: Linux version 4.5.1-1-ARCH (builduser@tobias) (gc
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: x86/fpu: Using 'lazy' FPU context switches.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000008
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000008f000-0x000000000008
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000090000-0x000000000009
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fff
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020000000-0x00000000200f
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020100000-0x00000000b882
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b8821000-0x00000000b885
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b8851000-0x00000000b8aa
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b8aa1000-0x00000000b93a
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b93a7000-0x00000000b9b3
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9b37000-0x00000000b9b9
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9b9b000-0x00000000b9b9
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9b9c000-0x00000000b9bd
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9bde000-0x00000000b9d5
lines 1-23...skipping...
-- Logs begin at čet 2016-04-21 15:50:11 CEST, end at pon 2016-05-23 15:50:33 CEST. --
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler systemd-journald[163]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/) is 8.0M, max 191.9M, 183.9M free.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler systemd-journald[163]: System journal (/var/log/journal/) is 8.0M, max 2.1G, 2.0G free.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler systemd-journald[163]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 1.805ms for 2 entries.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: Linux version 4.5.1-1-ARCH (builduser@tobias) (gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu A
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=963981da-a833-44f8-987a-863f22a68068 rw qui
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: x86/fpu: Using 'lazy' FPU context switches.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000008efff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000008f000-0x000000000008ffff] ACPI NVS
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000090000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fffffff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020000000-0x00000000200fffff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020100000-0x00000000b8820fff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b8821000-0x00000000b8850fff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b8851000-0x00000000b8aa0fff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b8aa1000-0x00000000b93a6fff] ACPI NVS
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b93a7000-0x00000000b9b36fff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9b37000-0x00000000b9b9afff] type 20
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9b9b000-0x00000000b9b9bfff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9b9c000-0x00000000b9bddfff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9bde000-0x00000000b9d53fff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9d54000-0x00000000b9ff9fff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b9ffa000-0x00000000b9ffffff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e00f8000-0x00000000e00f8fff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed01000-0x00000000fed01fff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffc00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000013fffffff] usable
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: efi:  ESRT=0xb9b33198  ACPI=0xb9332000  ACPI 2.0=0xb9332000  SMBIOS=0xf04d0  MPS=0xfd550
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x00000000b9b33198 to 0x00000000b9b331d0.
apr 21 15:50:11 Kepler kernel: SMBIOS 2.8 present.
```

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   256M  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0  21,5G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0  86,1G  0 part /home
└─sda5   8:5    0   3,8G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

EDIT:

It just froze again, this time with no applications running.

Output of dmesg | tail:

```
[    5.322285] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    5.336603] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    5.344733] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f2: link is not ready
[    5.427021] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: link down
[    5.427024] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: link down
[    5.427132] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f2: link is not ready
[    5.568331] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    6.408834] fuse init (API version 7.24)
[    6.977301] r8169 0000:03:00.2 enp3s0f2: link up
[    6.977321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0f2: link becomes ready
```

Also, usually the system only uses 3-15% of each core of cpu when it crashes, or 100% of one of the core when dwarf fortress is running.

Second EDIT:

I forgot to mention it before, but if the system falls asleep during the freeze, the system is still frozen after the login (but login is possible).

Third EDIT:

When I use the computer on hard surface (desk) the freezes occur less often than when I use it on soft surface (bed), so overheating may be a part of the problem (however they still do occur on hard surface and they weren't there when I had Debian and I was using it on soft surfaces even then).

Comment: Is this the fully dmesg ? Can you post the result of: dmesg | tail when the problem happens?